# Kibana 5.0 apache proxy and reverse-proxy configuration fails

Tags: apache, proxy, reverse-proxy, kibana-5

I'm trying to set a basic reverse proxy to access my kibana instance.
Here the kibana instance (working directly through :5601 without any problem)

```
#server.basePath: ""
server.basePath:"/kibana"
```

And my apache stuff

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Servername xxxx
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:5601
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:5601
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is I get 
http://xxxx/

> Proxy Error
>
> The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
>   The proxy server could not handle the request GET /app/kibana.
>
> Reason: DNS lookup failure for: localhost:5601app

I did some test but nothing seems to work.
Second try with
ProxyPass / http://localhost:5601/app/kibana
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:5601/app/kibana

This time it's better but still not OK
http://xxxx
I get  a blink where I can see 'kibana is loading' and right after a big red message

> Kibana did not load properly. Check the server output for more
>   information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, that was easy ...
The apache conf is (beware of the slashes)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Servername xxxx
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:5601/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:5601/
</VirtualHost>
```

And I let all by default on Kibana (no base.path)

Comment: "ProxyRequests" should be set to "Off" otherwise you just misconfigured an open proxy.  I'm editing this so that if someone cuts and pastes this verbatim they don't add another unsecured open proxy to the internet.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this

```
<VirtualHost *:8190>
    Servername kibana

    DirectoryIndex /app/kibana

    ProxyPass /app/kibana http://kibana:5601/app/kibana
    ProxyPassReverse /app/kibana http://kibana:5601/app/kibana

    ProxyPass /app/timelion http://kibana:5601/app/timelion
    ProxyPassReverse /app/timelion http://kibana:5601/app/timelion

    ProxyPass /bundles http://kibana:5601/bundles
    ProxyPassReverse /bundles http://kibana:5601/bundles

    ProxyPass /elasticsearch http://kibana:5601/elasticsearch
    ProxyPassReverse /elasticsearch http://kibana:5601/elasticsearch

    ProxyPass /status http://kibana:5601/status
    ProxyPassReverse /status http://kibana:/status

    ProxyPass /api/status http://kibana:5601/api/status
    ProxyPassReverse /api/status http://kibana:5601/api/status

    ProxyPass /api/console http://kibana:5601/api/console
    ProxyPassReverse /api/console http://kibana:5601/api/console

    ProxyPass /api/timelion/run http://kibana:5601/api/timelion/run
    ProxyPassReverse /api/timelion/run http://kibana:5601/api/timelion/run

    ProxyPass /api/timelion/functions http://kibana:5601/api/timelion/functions
    ProxyPassReverse /api/timelion/functions http://kibana:5601/api/timelion/functions

    ProxyPass /api/ http://kibana:5601/api/
    ProxyPassReverse /api/ http://kibana:5601/api/

    ProxyPass /goto/ http://kibana:5601/goto/
    ProxyPassReverse /goto/ http://kibana:5601/goto/

    ProxyPass /shorten http://kibana:5601/shorten
    ProxyPassReverse /shorten http://kibana:5601/shorten

    ProxyPass /plugins/kibana/ http://kibana:5601/plugins/kibana/
    ProxyPassReverse /plugins/kibana/ http://kibana:5601/plugins/kibana/

    ProxyPass /plugins/timelion/ http://kibana:5601/plugins/timelion/
    ProxyPassReverse /plugins/timelion/ http://kibana:5601/plugins/timelion/

    ProxyPass /app/sense http://kibana:5601/app/sense
    ProxyPassReverse /app/sense http://kibana:5601/app/sense

    ProxyPass /ui/fonts/open_sans/ http://kibana:5601/ui/fonts/open_sans/
    ProxyPassReverse /ui/fonts/open_sans/ http://kibana:5601/ui/fonts/open_sans/

    ProxyPass /es_admin/ http://kibana:5601/es_admin/
    ProxyPassReverse /es_admin/ http://kibana:5601/es_admin/

    ErrorLog "logs/kibana-error.log"

</VirtualHost>
```

Kibana 4 was less than half of that :)

Comment: Proposed a slightly improved answer below. To me it would not work without the /plugins proxy rule. Thanks! hj

Answer (score 1):

On Kibana 6.5.4 slightly different version of the answer by Sergiu Indrie (which I thank for the answer). To me it would not work without the plugins part.

```
    ProxyRequests On

    ProxyPass /KIB/app/kibana http://127.0.0.1:5601/app/kibana
    ProxyPassReverse /KIB/app/kibana http://127.0.0.1:5601/app/kibana

    ProxyPass /KIB/app/timelion http://127.0.0.1:5601/app/timelion
    ProxyPassReverse /KIB/app/timelion http://127.0.0.1:5601/app/timelion
    ProxyPass /KIB/bundles http://127.0.0.1:5601/bundles
    ProxyPassReverse /KIB/bundles http://127.0.0.1:5601/bundles
    ProxyPass /KIB/plugins http://127.0.0.1:5601/plugins
    ProxyPassReverse /KIB/plugins http://127.0.0.1:5601/plugins
    ProxyPass /KIB/elasticsearch http://127.0.0.1:5601/elasticsearch
    ProxyPassReverse /KIB/elasticsearch http://127.0.0.1:5601/elasticsearch
    ProxyPass /KIB/status http://127.0.0.1:5601/status
    ProxyPassReverse /KIB/status http://127.0.0.1:5601/status
    ProxyPass /KIB/api http://127.0.0.1:5601/api
    ProxyPassReverse /KIB/api http://127.0.0.1:5601/api
    ProxyPass /KIB/goto http://127.0.0.1:5601/goto
    ProxyPassReverse /KIB/goto http://127.0.0.1:5601/goto
    ProxyPass /KIB/shorten http://127.0.0.1:5601/shorten
    ProxyPassReverse /KIB/shorten http://127.0.0.1:5601/shorten

    <Directory /KIB/app/kibana/>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this more compact virtual host configuration on Apache/2.4.10:

```
<Location "/">
    Require all granted

    ProxyPass "http://127.0.0.1:5601/" keepalive=On
    ProxyPassReverse "http://127.0.0.1:5601/"
    #LogLevel alert trace5
</Location>
```

Answer (score 0):

`nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/kibana-vhost.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Servername xxxx.name.xyz
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:5601/
    ProxyPassReverse /(.*) http://localhost:5601/(.*)
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks,

this work for me...